# LaTeX Command line in OS X

Tags: errors, texlive, mac, terminal-output

I need to run latex from command line for a project on OS X. LaTeX is installed in:

> /usr/local/texlive/2010

in the bin folder there are three folders:

> /usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/universal-darwin 
>   /usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/win32 
>   /usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-darwin

both "universal-darwin" and "x86_64-darwin" have the executable file "latex". I ran this line in both of these directories and received the same error.

> ./latex /Users/fluid/Desktop/sample.tex

Here is the error

> fluid:x86_64-darwin fluid$ ./latex /Users/fluid/Desktop/sample.tex 
>    This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010) 
>    restricted \write18 enabled. 
>   entering extended mode 
>   ! I can't write on file `sample.log'. 
>   (Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.log')
>   Please type another transcript file name:

and here is the file sample.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
Sample \LaTeX{} file
\end{center}
Here is an equation
\begin{equation}
f(x) = e^x
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: @Fluid, There is however an alternative to run the file with TeXworks that comes with MacTeX. It's been running fine on my MBP. Your code works there. I just tried it. I never try on terminal.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: What does the terminal answer after you issue "`echo $PATH`"? (Without the quotes)

Comment: @Mico: I think your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't invoke latex (or pdflatex) from the folder that contains the executables, because that folder is (or at least should be...) writeable only by `root`. Thus, latex has to crash because it can't create the `.log`, `.aux`, and `.pdf` (or `.dvi`) files to the executables folder. You may verify this by typing

```
sudo ./latex /Users/fluid/Desktop/sample.tex
```

from within the executables folder, viz., `/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-darwin`: you'll be prompted for the superuser password, and thereafter latex should run without further complaints of the type you report in your posting. BTW, I *really* don't recommend doing this (i.e., running latex with superuser privileges) on a regular basis.

Assuming MacTeX was installed correctly, the TeX executables should be in the search path, and you should simply be running latex from the folder that contains the `.tex` file -- in the case you report, the `Desktop` folder.

By the way, you may want to think about updating your TeX distribution to MacTeX 2012.